# MemoryError when masking a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, out-of-memory

I have a numpy array of floats,  with a size of 14726008.
I am applying a boolean mask to this array, but the code is crashing due to a memory error.

For example, the following test/debug operation produces a memory error:

```
data_masked = data[np.ones(np.size(data), dtype=bool)]
```

Comment: what platform is this on? are you using 32 bit python or 64 bit?

Comment: I am using 64 bit python.

Answer (score 1):

The error was because the numpy array was actually a numpy array contained in a numpy array. I don't know why this causes a memoryerror, but calling data[0] instead fixes it.

Comment: i can only guess that having an array within an array added too much overhead, so was trying to use more RAM than you had available